# ATK4 - subfolder under page folder and js/css issue

Tags: php, user-interface, atk4

I am using agile toolkit for one of my projects. When I create a sub folder under page folder, CSS and JS are not picked from atk4 folder and I have to copy those css and js under templates folder. Is this the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Relative path,
Look:
Some Directory

```
templates/index.html { `<script src='test.js'></script>` }
index.php
```

If you want include `index.html` with `test.js` you must change relative path - from test.js to templates/test.js
edit: look : [Click](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With Agile Toolkit, the files are loaded from atk4/* by default. If you want to override any of those files including templates, css, images, classes or templates, you should copy them outside.

for example:

```
atk4/template/jui/css/general.css -> template/jui/css/general.css
atk4/lib/Tabs.php -> lib/Tabs.php
```

If you are including CSS files or linking to images, it's a good practices to use

```
<?template?>img/myimage.png<?/?>
```

in your own templates. That instruct Agile Toolkit to locate the resource and links to it properly.

Answer (score 0):

As romans said, you can put your own files in the /templates/default/css folder (It's called jui in 4.0 but default in 4.1) and these should be picked up by the pathfinder.

You can also add additional directories to the list searched by adding them in Frontend.php like this.

```
$this->addLocation('atk4-addons',array(
             'php'=>array(
                   'mvc',
                   'misc/lib',
                   'sterling/jqplot/lib',
                   ),
             'css'=>array(
                   'sterling/jqplot/templates/js/jqplot',
                   ),
```

so now the pathfinder will also search for css scripts in the directory specified and i can add the following line into my page code.

```
$p->api->template->append('css_include', '<link type="text/css" href="'.$this->api->locateURL('css','mysite.css').'" rel="stylesheet" />'."\n");
```